# How do I retrieve date in below format from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project. I have date calendar in my app, where user has to select date.

When they select date, say for example today's date, it will display in browser like this :

```
Mon 27 January 2014
```

In the database, I have a column `ReportDate` of `date` type. In database, it stores as `2014-01-27`. When I am storing, I am converting this to `DateTime`.

Now when I retrieve this date from database, in calendar field, it will display as `27/01/2014`.

But I need this to be display as `Mon 27 January 2014`.

Is there a way to achieve this??

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Depends on the **actual database** that you're using - but e.g. SQL Server doesn't store a `DATE` in any string format - it stores them as numerical data, so the **formatting** and presentation of that date stored in a table is totally and utterly the job of the **front-end**, e.g. your ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@string.format("{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}", theDate)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just made slight change like this :  @String.Format("{0:ddd d MMMM yyyy}", theDate).